# include facebook profile feed in website

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to access my public facebook profile feed and display the status updates on a website.
is there any easy way to do this?
I'd like to bypass the authorization process if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this:
by using the [facebook api](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) one can access a public facebook feed like this:

```
$this->facebookClient = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID,
      'secret' => FACBOOK_API_SECRET,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));
$this->facebookClient->api('/[facebook_name]/feed/');
```

where [facebook_name] is the name of your profile. this can be the ID or the name you choose as your facebook name.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot Bypass the Authorization Process. You need to authorize at least once. And Grant "offline_access" permission to your app, after that you can access your facebook wall from your app any time using the "token" which facebook will provide you after authorization. You will need to store that token.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fourgefeed framework and modify it to show your profile feed instead of the general community's...http://fourgefeed.com theirs a guide and download on it.

Answer (score 0):

be tricky .. if facebook won't allowing you to fetch your updated status .. why don't you connectyour profile with twitter .. as soon as you update something on facebook, it'll be automatically updated in twitter .. then use twitter API either json or xml to integrate it in your website . 
got what i'm saying ??